# How to connect MongoDB Shell with the external replicaset

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-shell

[image]

As it can be seen from the screenshot that the MongoDB shell is connected to the localhost. I want to connect it with an external replica set like this(given below) for my study purpose. But could not do so. Please suggest a way out.

```
"mongodb://m121:aggregations@cluster0-shard-00-00-jxeqq.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-01-jxeqq.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-02-jxeqq.mongodb.net:27017/aggregations?repilicaset=cluster0-shard-0" --authenticationDatabase admin --ssl -u m121 -p aggregations --norc
```

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots, use formatted text. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3027266

Comment: What so you mean by "But could not do so"? Do you get any error? If yes, what is the error message?

Comment: Do you disclose your credentials in the question?

Comment: You misspelled replicaset in the URI option.

Answer (score 0):

What IP-addresses mongod is listening? (mongod.conf, net.bindIp or net.bindIpAll)

If you don't have either there, then the system is listening only localhost address.

[config-file net-options](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/#net-options)